# Error in scale.default: length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'

Tags: r, regression

I am using `mboost` package to do some classification. Here is the code

```
library('mboost')
load('so-data.rdata')
model <- glmboost(is_exciting~., data=training, family=Binomial())
pred <- predict(model, newdata=test, type="response")
```

But R complains when doing prediction that

```
Error in scale.default(X, center = cm, scale = FALSE) : 
  length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'
```

The data (`training` and `test`) can be downloaded here ([7z](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1335302/so-data.7z), [zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1335302/so-data.zip)). 
What is the reason of the error and how to get rid of it? Thank you.

**UPDATE**:

```
> str(training)
'data.frame':   439599 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ is_exciting                           : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ school_state                          : Factor w/ 52 levels "AK","AL","AR",..: 15 5 5 23 47 5 44 42 42 5 ...
 $ school_charter                        : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ school_magnet                         : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ school_year_round                     : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ school_nlns                           : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ school_charter_ready_promise          : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ teacher_prefix                        : Factor w/ 6 levels "","Dr.","Mr.",..: 5 5 3 5 6 5 6 6 5 6 ...
 $ teacher_teach_for_america             : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ teacher_ny_teaching_fellow            : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ primary_focus_subject                 : Factor w/ 28 levels "","Applied Sciences",..: 19 17 18 18 10 4 17 17 18 17 ...
 $ primary_focus_area                    : Factor w/ 8 levels "","Applied Learning",..: 6 5 5 5 5 4 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ secondary_focus_subject               : Factor w/ 28 levels "","Applied Sciences",..: 28 18 17 19 26 18 18 28 24 25 ...
 $ secondary_focus_area                  : Factor w/ 8 levels "","Applied Learning",..: 7 5 5 6 8 5 5 7 7 4 ...
 $ resource_type                         : Factor w/ 7 levels "","Books","Other",..: 4 4 2 5 5 2 2 5 5 5 ...
 $ poverty_level                         : Factor w/ 4 levels "high poverty",..: 2 2 4 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ grade_level                           : Factor w/ 5 levels "","Grades 3-5",..: 5 5 2 5 5 2 3 2 4 2 ...
 $ fulfillment_labor_materials           : num  30 35 35 30 30 35 30 35 35 35 ...
 $ total_price_excluding_optional_support: num  1274 477 892 548 385 ...
 $ total_price_including_optional_support: num  1499 562 1050 645 453 ...
 $ students_reached                      : int  31 20 250 36 19 28 90 21 60 56 ...
 $ eligible_double_your_impact_match     : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ eligible_almost_home_match            : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ essay_length                          : int  236 285 194 351 383 273 385 437 476 159 ...


> str(test)
'data.frame':   44772 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ school_state                          : Factor w/ 51 levels "AK","AL","AR",..: 22 35 11 46 5 35 11 28 28 10 ...
 $ school_charter                        : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ school_magnet                         : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ school_year_round                     : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ school_nlns                           : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ school_charter_ready_promise          : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ teacher_prefix                        : Factor w/ 6 levels "","Dr.","Mr.",..: 3 5 6 6 3 5 5 5 3 5 ...
 $ teacher_teach_for_america             : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ teacher_ny_teaching_fellow            : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ primary_focus_subject                 : Factor w/ 28 levels "","Applied Sciences",..: 5 16 17 17 18 11 16 17 2 17 ...
 $ primary_focus_area                    : Factor w/ 8 levels "","Applied Learning",..: 2 4 5 5 5 2 4 5 6 5 ...
 $ secondary_focus_subject               : Factor w/ 28 levels "","Applied Sciences",..: 25 1 19 1 17 9 17 11 1 1 ...
 $ secondary_focus_area                  : Factor w/ 8 levels "","Applied Learning",..: 4 1 6 1 5 6 5 2 1 1 ...
 $ resource_type                         : Factor w/ 7 levels "","Books","Other",..: 5 5 5 2 5 6 4 5 5 4 ...
 $ poverty_level                         : Factor w/ 4 levels "high poverty",..: 1 2 4 4 1 2 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ grade_level                           : Factor w/ 5 levels "","Grades 3-5",..: 4 3 3 5 4 5 5 4 3 5 ...
 $ fulfillment_labor_materials           : num  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 ...
 $ total_price_excluding_optional_support: num  2185 149 1017 156 860 ...
 $ total_price_including_optional_support: num  2571 175 1197 183 1012 ...
 $ students_reached                      : int  200 110 10 22 180 51 30 15 260 20 ...
 $ eligible_double_your_impact_match     : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ eligible_almost_home_match            : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ essay_length                          : int  221 137 313 243 373 344 304 431 231 173 ...


> summary(model)

     Generalized Linear Models Fitted via Gradient Boosting

Call:
glmboost.formula(formula = is_exciting ~ ., data = training,     family = Binomial())


     Negative Binomial Likelihood 

Loss function: { 
     f <- pmin(abs(f), 36) * sign(f) 
     p <- exp(f)/(exp(f) + exp(-f)) 
     y <- (y + 1)/2 
     -y * log(p) - (1 - y) * log(1 - p) 
 } 


Number of boosting iterations: mstop = 100 
Step size:  0.1 
Offset:  -1.197806 

Coefficients: 

NOTE: Coefficients from a Binomial model are half the size of coefficients
 from a model fitted via glm(... , family = 'binomial').
See Warning section in ?coef.mboost

                       (Intercept)                     school_stateDC 
                     -0.5250166130                       0.0426909965 
                    school_stateIL                    school_chartert 
                      0.0084191638                       0.0729272310 
                teacher_prefixMrs.                  teacher_prefixMs. 
                     -0.0181489492                       0.0438425925 
        teacher_teach_for_americat                 resource_typeBooks 
                      0.2593005345                       0.0046126706 
           resource_typeTechnology        fulfillment_labor_materials 
                     -0.0313904871                       0.0120086140 
eligible_double_your_impact_matcht        eligible_almost_home_matcht 
                     -0.0316376431                      -0.0522717398 
                      essay_length 
                      0.0004993224 
attr(,"offset")
[1] -1.197806

Selection frequencies:
       fulfillment_labor_materials         teacher_teach_for_americat 
                              0.24                               0.15 
                      essay_length                    school_chartert 
                              0.15                               0.09 
                 teacher_prefixMs.            resource_typeTechnology 
                              0.08                               0.07 
eligible_double_your_impact_matcht        eligible_almost_home_matcht 
                              0.07                               0.07 
                teacher_prefixMrs.                     school_stateDC 
                              0.04                               0.02 
                    school_stateIL                 resource_typeBooks 
                              0.01                               0.01
```

I also tried `glm` but it said

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor teacher_prefix has new levels
```

But I don't see any new levels in the `teacher_prefix` variable:

```
> levels(training$teacher_prefix)
[1] ""           "Dr."        "Mr."        "Mr. & Mrs." "Mrs."       "Ms."       
> levels(test$teacher_prefix)
[1] ""           "Dr."        "Mr."        "Mr. & Mrs." "Mrs."       "Ms."
```

Comment: I'm unable to open your attachment. Perhaps you could edit your question to incldude the results of `str(training)` and `str(test)` and `summary(model)`.

Comment: @MrFlick I've updated the question. Do you mean you cannot download the file, cannot extract the `.7z` file, or cannot load the `.rdata` file into R?

Comment: I can't extract a 7z file.

Comment: @MrFlick A link for zip format is attached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the problems with `glmboost` and `glm` are related. There are problems with your `teacher_prefix` variable.

As the `glm` example points out, there are levels that are in `test` that are not in `training` (kind of). While both factors have the same `levels()`, the training set has no observations where `teacher_prefix==""` but test does. Compare

```
table(test$teacher_prefix)
table(training$teacher_prefix)
```

So `glm` is actually giving the more accurate, helpful error message. The problem is the same with `glmboost` although it isn't as direct about saying it.

Doing this seemed to "fix" it

```
test2 <- subset(test, teacher_prefix %in% c("Dr.","Mr.","Mrs.","Ms."))
test2$teacher_prefix <- droplevels(test2$teacher_prefix)
pred <- predict(model, newdata=test2, type="response")
```

We just get rid of the unused levels and then do the standard prediction.

Comment: Thank you. I thought `levels` would print used levels.