# Several problems encountered when doing Discriminant analysis in R

Tags: r

I encountered some problems when when doing Discriminant analysis in R.

The first one was that when I finished the LDA analysis using the package MASS, I can't plot it. The error was:

```
Error in scale.default(X, center = means, scale = FALSE) : 
length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'
```

Some part of the code：

```
library(MASS)
varaslda<-lda(class~rail+eco+class)
varaslda
plot(varaslda)
```

Another problem was that somehow I couldn't predict the class using the LDA model I already generated. The error was:

```
> class.pre<-predict(varaslda)$class
Error in predict.lda(varaslda) : wrong number of variables
```

Can anybody help me solve these problems? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  If I use the reproducible example in the help page of `?lda`, it is working.

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224554/error-in-scale-default-length-of-center-must-equal-the-number-of-columns-of

Comment: Well problem solved...I found the mistake myself...a very stupid one.

Comment: the line `varaslda<-lda(class~rail+eco+class)` should be `varaslda<-lda(class~rail+eco)`..... But thank you two for your time :)  @akrun @Hack-R